# What is a 2-dimensional key-value format that Api Blueprint can understand?

Tags: rest, url, apiblueprint, dredd

I'm developing api documentation for a RESTful search API using Api Blueprint.  I would like to be able to pass filters to the API so I can assemble:

```
filter[filtername1]=filtervalue1
filter[filtername2]=filtervalue2
```

Per this question, I'm using percent encoded square brackets, but unlike this question, it's not possible for us to describe every possible key name:

[How to format hash-based parameters in the URL when creating Blueprint API doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004098/how-to-format-hash-based-parameters-in-the-url-when-creating-blueprint-api-doc)

I want the key name to be variable, since it could be any field in the source data.  Does this work?

```
## Key-Value-Test [/api/v1/keyvaluetest?term={term}&filter%5B{field_name}%5D={field_value}]

+ term
+ filter_field
+ filter_value
```

Is there a recommended format for a two-dimensional array like this? It doesn't seem like this would work in Dredd because `+ filter_field` doesn't really match `filter[filter_field]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API Blueprint uses [URI Templates standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570). There are ways to express and expand arrays (see [section 3.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-3.2.1)), however, it expects "standard URI approach", meaning the URI would be expanded as follows:

`/api/v1/keyvaluetest?term=yourterm&filter=filtervalue1&filter=filtervalue2`

which is a "standard" way of doing arrays, except the most popular web language popularised your way back in 2000s.

The templates are designed for expansion: give it a bunch of variables and a string, and you'll get a properly-formatted string. As far as I am aware, there is no "wild match" (inserting pattern-match variables at a certain position in string).

The only solution I can think of within the realm of URL templates would be taking advantage of explosion modifier (see [composite values](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-2.4.2)):

`/api/v1/keyvaluetest{?keys*}`

which, given associative array of values `[(filter%5Bfiltername1%5D, filtervalue1), (filter%5Bfiltername2%5D, filtervalue2) ]` *should* expand properly.

However, I am not sure how to specify those in [MSON](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson) as I don't think there is a support for "dynamic keys" and I think most of the tooling wouldn't handle it (yet).

Might be [worth asking](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson/issues).

Answer (score 5):

I am afraid that API Blueprint and Apiary does not yet allow these kind of dynamic URL definitions.

API Blueprint and Apiary only allows URI Templates as defined in [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570)

The following URI Template is not valid according to that RFC

```
GET /resource?year={year}&month={month}
```

You can change the URL to define something like the following:

```
## Key-Value-Test [/api/v1/keyvaluetest{?term,field_name,field_value}]

+ Parameters
    + term: a
    + field_name: b
    + field_value: c
```

There are two caveats with this method:

- You can only give one field name and field value for the parameters. If you want more field parameters, you have to extend the URL.
- You have to change the API url which I don't think you would want to.

Please start a feature request at http://support.apiary.io if you have any.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that @PavanKumarSunkara is an Apiary developer.

Comment: Note the URI template does not seems to be correct. Instead of "?term={term}" you want just "{?term}" see https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#uri-template-variable

Comment: Also related – http://support.apiary.io/knowledgebase/articles/106871-uri-templates-support